# Java Abstract class Unusual behavior

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract

**Abstract Class:**

```
   public abstract class ParentClass {
    private static ParentClass mpParentClass;

    public ParentClass() {
        mpParentClass = this;
    }

    public abstract void method1();

    public static ParentClass getInstance() {
        return mpParentClass;
    }
}
```

**Child Class :**

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    @Override
    public void method1() {
        System.out.print("ChildClass class method");
    }
}
```

**Test Class :**

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         ChildClass cl = new ChildClass();
        ParentClass.getInstance().method1();
    }
}
```

Here I have created an abstract class and a Child class which extends the parent Abstract class.

Parent abstract class holds a reference to its own instance and returns the instance through a static method.

In Test class, if I don't create an object of ChildClass, java throws NullPointerException.

But after creating object of ChildClass, and then querying instance of ParentClass and invoking abstract method, it calls method implemented by ChildClass.

I am unable to understand this behavior . Please anyone explain.

Answer (score 3):

The first time you Instantiate a ChildClass you use the default constructor of parentClass which instantiate the private field with the ChildClass type . If you don't do that, the private field mpParentClass  is not instantiate. So you have a NullPointerException

Answer (score 3):

`ParentClass.getInstance()` is a static method so it doesn't require an instance of your class to run.

By calling this method you will return the static member `mpParentClass`.
But by default this member contains a `null` reference.

So without doing anything this will indeed result in a `NullPointerException` because you didn't call the constructor of `ParentClass`.

---

In your example you first make an instance of the `ChildClass`.

This will call the default constructor of that class. This default constructor has the standard behavior of calling the default constructor of the super class (by calling `super()`).

So by instantiating the `ChildClass` you call the constructor of `ParentClass` that will set the `mpParentClass` datamember to this. And here this refers to the instance of the `ChildClass` you are creating.

So after construction `mpParentClass` will contain the newly created instance of the `ChildClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening.

When you call the constructor for your `ChildClass`, it's implicit that the first *actual* call in that method is to the superclass constructor. If you had a superclass constructor that required/allowed alternate arguments, you could call it manually. But it's happening for you.

When the superclass constructor is called, a `static` reference is being assigned to that new instance, which *is* a `ChildClass` instance. (Because that's what `this` is, in this case.)

If you were to call:

```
new ChildClass();
new ParentClass() {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("Anonymous class!");
    }
};
ParentClass.getInstance().method1();
```

You would see `"Anonymous class!"`, because there is one *static* reference that is going to be reassigned every time you create any instance of a `ParentClass` implementation.

Regarding your `NullPointerException` - the only place where `mpParentClass` is assigned to a value is in the constructor for `ParentClass`. If you never create an instance of a `ParentClass`, then this code will never be called, and `mpParentClass` will be left with its original value, which is `null`. Attempting to call a method or access a property on a `null` reference is what produces a `NullPointerException`.

The question to ask is: If you never instantiate any of your implementations (by 'calling' their constructors), what do you *expect* the `mpParentClass` variable to be set to, if not `null`?

Answer (score 0):

Parent class is abstract so you can't use the constructor directly. The static variable instance is null by default which leads to your NullPointerException. The only way to set this variable is by calling the constructor which is only called when a constructor of a child class is called.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are only assigning to the static field `mpParentClass` in your `ParentClass` constructor.  Therefore, until you create an instance of `ChildClass`, `mpParentClass` is null. In your example, the base class `ParentClass` constructor is called implicitly when you create an instance of the derived class `ChildClass`.

Might I suggest that you use the [singleton pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton/java/1) instead?

```
public class Singleton {
  // Private constructor prevents instantiation from other classes
  private Singleton() {}

 /**
   * SingletonHolder is loaded on the first execution of Singleton.getInstance() 
   * or the first access to SingletonHolder.INSTANCE, not before.
   */
  private static class SingletonHolder { 
    private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
  }

  public static Singleton getInstance() {
    return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're creating a `ChildClass` then calling its `method1()` through unnecessary trickery.

You do realize that `this` will be a `ChildClass` instance at the `ParentClass` constructor, right? It has to be, since the parent class is abstract and therefore there can never be a `this` instance that would represent it.

Comment: I don't think he does, which is why he's asking.

Comment: @CraigOtis That's not very helpful. I gave the answer in the second paragraph.

Comment: Fair enough. Downvote removed. Your answer (`"unnecessary trickery"`, `"you do realize..."`) just comes off as a little condescending, especially from the perspective of a beginner.

Comment: I didn't mean it as condescending, I meant that it's the exact equivalent of calling the method directly on the created instance, instead of retrieving the reference from the parent class and then calling it.